# Как решить задачу без большого числа переменных

Tags: python, коллекции, переменные

Необходимо найти дни недели, когда никто не может работать, и для каждого дня найти количество сотрудников, которые могут дежурить в этот день. Вопрос по второму пункту. Как решить задачу без использования большого количества переменных, желательно, используя коллекции.

Вот код:

```
shedule = {
    '1001': ['пн', 'вс'],
    '1231': ['пн', 'вт'],
    '1232': ['ср', 'чт', 'пт'],
    '1280': ['ср', 'пт', 'вс'],
    '1282': ['чт'],
    '1290': ['пт', 'вс'],
    '1303': ['вт', 'вс'],
}
unique_days = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс']
shedule_set1 = []
shedule_set = []
tmp = []
tmp1 = []
mon = 0
tue = 0
wed = 0
thu = 0
fri = 0
sat = 0
sun = 0
for j in shedule:
    shedule_set1.append(shedule[j])
for i in shedule_set1:
    tmp1.append(i)
    for j in tmp1:
        tmp = j
    for m in tmp:
        shedule_set.append(m)
for i in shedule_set:
    if i == "пн":
        mon += 1
    elif i == "вт":
        tue += 1
    elif i == "ср":
        wed += 1
    elif i == "чт":
        thu += 1
    elif i == "пт":
        fri += 1
    elif i == "сб":
        sat += 1
    elif i == "вс":
        sun += 1
shedule_set = set(shedule_set)
unique_days = set(unique_days)

print("В этот день никто не может дежурить:", unique_days.difference(shedule_set))
print("пн -", mon, "вт -", tue, "ср -", wed, "чт -", thu, "пт -", fri, "сб -", sat, "вс -", sun)
```

Answer (score 2):

а почему бы не объединить все в списки:

вместо

```
mon = 0
tue = 0
wed = 0
thu = 0
fri = 0
sat = 0
sun = 0
```

пусть будет

```
week_days = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

а вместо

```
if i == "пн":
    mon += 1
elif i == "вт":
    tue += 1
elif i == "ср":
    wed += 1
elif i == "чт":
    thu += 1
elif i == "пт":
    fri += 1
elif i == "сб":
    sat += 1
elif i == "вс":
    sun += 1
```

использовать

```
day = {'пн': 0, 'вт': 1, 'ср': 2, 'чт': 3, 'пт': 4, 'сб': 5, 'вс': 6}

week_days[day[i]] += 1
```

или еще проще:

```
week_days = {'пн': 0, 'вт': 0, 'ср': 0, 'чт': 0, 'пт': 0, 'сб': 0, 'вс': 0}

...

week_days[i] += 1

...
```

и вместо

```
print("пн -", mon, "вт -", tue, "ср -", wed, "чт -", thu, "пт -", fri, "сб -", sat, "вс -", sun)
```

сделать:

```
print(', '.join(f"{item[0]} - {item[1]}" for item in week_days.items()))
```

или

```
print(*[f"{item[0]} - {item[1]}" for item in week_days.items()], sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут логично использовать словарь вместо отдельных переменных, где ключ - день недели, значение - количество "попаданий" в день недели.

Пример на обычном словаре:

```
week = dict()

...

for i in shedule_set:
    if i not in week:
        week[i] = 0  # Если данный день еще не попадался, инициализируем нулём
    
    week[i] += 1

shedule_set = set(shedule_set)
# unique_days тут не преобразовываем в set, чтобы сохранился порядок,
# и можно было в цикле вывести значения по порядку дней недели

print("В этот день никто не может дежурить:", set(unique_days).difference(shedule_set))

for day in unique_days:
    print(day, "-", week[day], end=" ")

print()
```

Можно упростить через defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

...

week = defaultdict(int)  # При запросе значение по отсутствующему ключу будет возвращать 0

...


for i in shedule_set:
    week[i] += 1

shedule_set = set(shedule_set)

print("В этот день никто не может дежурить:", set(unique_days).difference(shedule_set))

for day in unique_days:
    print(day, "-", week[day], end=" ")

print()
```

Или через `Counter` (он автоматом посчитает сколько раз каждый объект встретился в исходном списке или любой другой итерируемой последовательнсти):

```
from collections import Counter

...

week = Counter(shedule_set)

shedule_set = set(shedule_set)

print("В этот день никто не может дежурить:", set(unique_days).difference(shedule_set))

for day in unique_days:
    print(day, "-", week[day], end=" ")

print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `Counter` уже здесь предлагалось. Мне это тоже первым пришло в голову. Получилось как-то так:

```
from collections import Counter

shedule = {
    '1001': ['пн', 'вс'],
    '1231': ['пн', 'вт'],
    '1232': ['ср', 'чт', 'пт'],
    '1280': ['ср', 'пт', 'вс'],
    '1282': ['чт'],
    '1290': ['пт', 'вс'],
    '1303': ['вт', 'вс'],
}
unique_days = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс']

c = Counter()
for k in shedule.values(): 
    c += Counter(k)
    
print(*[f'{i} - {j}' for i,j in sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x: unique_days.index(x[0]))],sep='\n')
print('В этот день никто не может дежурить: ', ','.join(set(unique_days)-c.keys()))
```

результат:

```
пн - 2
вт - 2
ср - 2
чт - 2
пт - 3
вс - 4
В этот день никто не может дежурить:  сб
```